# angularJS adding ng-href only if present in javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following javascript object that I'm building my navigation bar from:

```
$scope.slo = [
    {
      main: "IJS",
      url: "https://www.ijs.si/ijsw"
    },
    {
      main: "ZIC",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom",
      submenu: [{
        one: "predstavitev",
        two: "osebje"
      }]
    },
    {
      main: "knjižnica",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom",
      submenu: [{
        one: "tiskane revije",
        two: "elektronske revije",
        three: "baze podatkov",
        four: "katalog(COBISS)"
      }]
    },
    {
      main: "storitve",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom",
      submenu: [{
        one: "bibliografije",
        two: "medknjižnična izposoja",
        three: "fotokopirnica"
      }]
    }
    ];

    $scope.eng = [{
      main: "IJS"
    },
    {
      main: "ZIC",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom",
      submenu: [{
        one: "introduction",
        two: "staff"
      }]
    },
    {
      main: "library",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom",
      submenu: [{
        one: "printed journals",
        two: "electronic journals",
        three: "databases",
        four: "catalogue(COBISS)"
      }]
    },
    {
      main: "services",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom",
      submenu: [{
        one: "bibliographies",
        two: "interlibrary loan",
        three: "copy room"
      }]
    }];
```

Now I want to add a `ng-href` markup to my html, but only if the `url` property is present. So for instance the first bar would point to an url, but the rest of them would not since they are drop downs.

This is my html markup:

```
<a ng-href="{{!menu.url}}">{{ menu.main }}<span ng-class="menu.icon"></span></a>
```

My question is, can I put a condition for `ng-href` to evaluate whether the `url` property is present, and then bind the urls property value? And if I can, how do I do it?

With my current markup I only get:

```
<a href="false" class="ng-binding" ng-href="false">IJS<span ng-class="menu.icon"></span></a>
<a href="true" class="ng-binding" ng-href="true">ZIC<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" ng-class="menu.icon"></span></a>
```

Comment: ng-href is the url value, not a boolean option. just remove the `!` and it'll be blank if the url doesn't exist, which won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `ng-attr-*` to conditionally add attributes to your markup

```
<a ng-attr-href="{{menu.url}}">{{ menu.main }}<span ng-class="menu.icon"></span></a>
```

This will add `href` attribute to your anchor tag only when there's a valid value for `menu.url`. If `{{menu.url}}` resolves to `undefined` then `href` attribute will not be added to your element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-if` property with function like this

```
<a ng-href="{{menu.url}}">{{ menu.main }}<span ng-class="menu.icon" ng-if = "isExistUrl(menu.url)"></span></a>
```

write a function in controller

```
$scope.isExistUrl = function(url){
   // Write logic here if exist return true else false
}
```